# Merge multiple dataframes with Reduce() and list()

Tags: r, list, merge

I need to merge a lot of dataframes with sequential names (df1, df2, df3, ...) by the first column.

If I use the code below (assuming 3 dataframes), it runs correctly:

```
merged_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))
```

But I have 100 dataframes.
How can I change the code in order to do not have to write manually the list of dataframes?

I have tried in this way:

```
df_list <- lapply(paste0("df",1:100), as.name)
merged_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df_list))
```

but it doesn't function...

Comment: You can't just add variable names as characters. `"df1" ` is not the same as `df1`. One is a character, the other is a name. You should fill the list of dataframes at the moment you are reading them. I assume that they are stored in files or a database and you read them from this source. While reading, you can just append them to a list instead of storing each one to a new variable. Then, you can access them as `df_list[[i]]` for the i-th dataframe. Or you can use the complete list as an argument in your `Reduce()` call.

Comment: Thank you @MartinWettstein for your suggestion, I have implemented it in this way and it runs: `file_names = list.files(pattern=".xlsx$")`(it takes all the file in the directory with the extetion .xlsx, but I put in the directory only my dataframes df1.xlsx, df2.xlxs, etc. and it append them in the list all at once) , `df_list = lapply(file_names, read_excel, sheet=1)` and `merged_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), df_list)`

Comment: Yep, that looks like a clean solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `mget()` all the dataframes into a list from the working environment as follows:

```
df_list <- mget(paste0("df",1:100))
merged_df <- Reduce(
  function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), 
  df_list
)
```

Note that a better solution would be to create/read these dataframes into a list in the first place, not into distinct objects.

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` option

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
mget(str_c('df', 1:100)) %>%
    reduce(full_join)
```